# How can I see calendars written by a Service Account in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, calendar

I managed to authenticate thru OAuth2.0 and create a calendar service from serviceaccount, then add some calendars (say 2661j6vlkriufg0ug8e2dtlbps@group.calendar.google.com), storing their id. But when I try to add events to those calendars, even if there's NO error and the "events.insert.execute" returns an event as expected, as soon as I try to read those inserted events from these calendars, no event is returned, nor I am able to see or add these calendards to my main one. How can I achieve these goals? How can I see what is the Group name?

Here is the code:

```
Private Const SVCACCMAIL = "nnnnnnnnnnnnn-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmmmmmmmmmm@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
Private Const ACTIVITY_ID = "x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9"

Public Function GetCert() As X509Certificate2
    Dim fileCert As String
    If System.IO.File.Exists("D:\inetpub\wwwroot\UGO_Cont.Web\UGO-Adv-CRM-nnnnnnnnaaaaaaa.p12") Then
        fileCert = "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\UGO_Cont.Web\UGO-Adv-CRM-nnnnnnnnnnna.p12"
    Else
        fileCert = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UGO_Cont.Web\UGO-Adv-CRM-nnnnnnnnnnnna.p12"
    End If
    Dim cert = New X509Certificate2(fileCert, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
    Return cert
End Function

<OperationContract()>
Public Function InsertEvent(authToken As String, id_Azienda As Integer, id_Azione As Integer, id_Op As Integer) As String
    Dim lscop = New List(Of String)
    lscop.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
    Dim scopes As IEnumerable(Of String) = lscop
    'Dim inzlzr As New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SVCACCMAIL) With {.User = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", .Scopes = scopes}
    'Dim inzlzr As New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SVCACCMAIL) With {.User = SVCACCMAIL, .Scopes = scopes}
    Dim inzlzr As New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SVCACCMAIL) With {.Scopes = scopes}
    Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(inzlzr.FromCertificate(GetCert))
    Dim ptx As New Pratiche_Entities
    Dim azsCrm = From a In ptx.Azioni Where a.Id_Azienda = id_Azienda AndAlso a.Id_Azione = id_Azione
    If azsCrm IsNot Nothing And azsCrm.Count = 1 Then
        Dim taskOp = InsertEventAsync(credential, azsCrm.First)
    End If
End Function

Async Function InsertEventAsync(cr As ServiceAccountCredential, azCrm As Azioni) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Dim otx As New OperAziende_Entities
    Dim ops = From o In otx.Operatori Where o.Id_Azienda = azCrm.Id_Azienda AndAlso o.Id_Operatore = azCrm.id_OperatoreAssegnato
    If ops IsNot Nothing AndAlso ops.Count = 1 AndAlso ops.First.Mail_Operatore IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim op = ops.First
        Dim GetToken = cr.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)
        Dim ok As Boolean = Await GetToken
        Dim service As New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.ApplicationName = "UGO_Adv CRM", .HttpClientInitializer = cr})
        Dim Id = Nothing
        'list calendars
        Dim list As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()
        Dim flgupd As Boolean = False
        For Each l In list
            'Dim url=l.
            If l.Summary = Op.Mail_Operatore Then
                Id = l.Id
                If Op.CalendarId Is Nothing OrElse Op.CalendarId <> Id Then
                    Op.CalendarId = Id
                    flgupd = True
                    Dim evts = service.Events.List(Id).Execute
                    Dim evs = evts
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Id Is Nothing Then
            'insert new calendar
            Dim newCal = service.Calendars.Insert(New Calendar() With {.Summary = Op.Mail_Operatore}).Execute
            Id = newCal.Id
            Op.CalendarId = Id
            flgupd = True
        End If
        If flgupd Then
            otx.SaveChanges()
        End If
        'insert a new event

        Dim lAtts As New List(Of EventAttendee)
        Dim att As New EventAttendee() With {.Email = op.Mail_Operatore, .DisplayName = op.Dsc_Operatore}
        lAtts.Add(att)
        Dim atts As IList(Of EventAttendee) = lAtts

        'Dim lrmnd As New List(Of EventReminder)
        'lrmnd.Add(New EventReminder() With {.Method = "email", .Minutes = 30})
        'Dim rmnds As IList(Of EventReminder) = lrmnd
        Try
            Dim newEvt As New [Event]()
            With newEvt
                .Summary = azCrm.Cod_VociTipologiaAzioni + " x " + CStr(azCrm.Id_Anagrafica)
                .Attendees = atts
                '.Reminders = rmnds
                .Description = azCrm.Dsc_Azione
                .Start = New EventDateTime() With {.DateTime = Format(azCrm.data_attesa_esecuzione, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00").Replace(".", ":"), .TimeZone = "Europe/Rome"}
                .End = New EventDateTime() With {.DateTime = Format(If(azCrm.fine_attesa_esecuzione, azCrm.data_attesa_esecuzione), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00").Replace(".", ":"), .TimeZone = "Europe/Rome"}
            End With
            Dim evReq = service.Events.Insert(newEvt, Id)
            evReq.SendNotifications = True
            Dim ev = evReq.Execute
            Dim ev1 = ev
        Catch ex As Google.GoogleApiException
            Dim err = ex.Message
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post some code of what you're doing when you add it?

Comment: of course. Here it is:

Comment: Have you stepped through and confirmed that the events you're grabbing to add to the calendar are actually there and not a list of nothing? For example the line starting with "Dim list As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) ="